# Print an AVL Tree to a JTextPane : Java

Tags: java, avl-tree

I've created an AVL Tree, with working Add and Remove methods. However, I need to print out the tree in a visual format. For example, if the balanced tree currently contained 1, 2, 3 it would look something like this:

```
   3
2
   1
```

Is there a relatively straightforward way to do this?? (You can assume my tree will always be properly balanced after a value has been added or removed.)

Answer (score 1):

For what you want there is a simple algorithm that'll work not too bad depending on your demands. In general (ie drawing nodes) this problem is quite hard to solve - and if I'm not completely mistaken NP hard in 3d (but there are some good genetic algorithms for that too).

Anyways I've used something similar quick n' dirty for debugging purposes but I think it should at least give you an idea how it can work (c# code, but then the differences here come down to different capitalization):

```
                    // Start Method
        static internal string PrintTree(Node root) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            PrintTree(root, "", sb);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        static private void PrintTree(Node node, string indent, StringBuilder sb) {
            sb.AppendLine(node.ToString());
            if (node.LeftChild != null) {
                if (node.RightChild == null) {
                    PrintLastChild(node.LeftChild, indent, sb);
                }
                else {
                    PrintNormalChild(node.LeftChild, indent, sb);
                    PrintLastChild(node.RightChild, indent, sb);
                }
            }
        }

        static private void PrintNormalChild(Node node, string indent, StringBuilder sb) {
            sb.Append(indent);
            sb.Append('├');
            sb.Append('─');
            PrintTree(node, indent + "│ ", sb);
        }

        static private void PrintLastChild(Node node, string indent, StringBuilder sb) {
            sb.Append(indent);
            sb.Append('└');
            sb.Append('─');
            PrintTree(node, indent + "  ", sb);
        }
```

If you want it in a more typical tree fashion you'll have to do some precomputations (basically since you'd want the root node in the middle of the tree you'd have to know the depth to compute the necessary indention level and work line for line - shouldn't be too bad if efficiency isn't important)